# Amazon document db 4.0 compatibility with mongodb 4.4

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, mongodump

Amazon documentdb 4.0 compatibility with mongodb 4.4

I use amazon documentdb version 4.0.
I also have another ubuntu server 20.04 and there is mongodb 4.4
In this way, I want dump amazon documentdb in ubunt20.04 so, I use mongodump but it cant't dump data.
Is it imposible dump data with mongodb 4.4?
amazon documentdb 4.0 is not compatible with mongodb 4.4?
if not, which mongodb version I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can export data from Amazon DocumentDB 4.0 using mongodump/mongoexport and then import it to MongoDB 4.4. Is there a specific error you're getting, why you can't mongodump?